# Not able to hide Choice-Indicator of the QComboBox

Tags: checkbox, stylesheet, indicator, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

programmer

When I set the background-color of the list view belonging to the **QComboBox** (per QSS), then this QComboBox will no more use the built-in-opticel-look-and feel. Instaed I have to specify all optical settings also per QSS-Stylesheet:

```
QComboBox QListView {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

The list view, which shows the chosable item, displays a checkbox on the left now. This box is checked for those item, chosen on last usage.

**How can i hide the column with the checkboxes, so that they will be unvisible and will not be consume any space on the screen?**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

**QSS Workaround for a difficult draw topic of QComboBox**

If you don't use a QSS block, the QComboBox is drawn with its OS-Look-and-Feel. If you are starting to specify QSS rules some or all subcontrols of the QComboBox begin to lose the OS-Look-and-Feel. In worst case you have to specify all properties in QSS now.

Subject of this article is the choice indicator, drawn by the QStyleViewItem class, a render helper implemented in .../src/gui/widgets/qcombobox_p.h within the QT sources. This functionality seems to be unpossible modifyable by a subclass of QProxyStyle which can be used in other cases for hard layout problems.

However, I found a solution in QSS by specifying a well chosen set of rules:

```
/* Background color of popup-list.*/ 
QComboBox QListView{
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
/* Needed to complete the rule set. */
QComboBox::item:alternate {
    background: white;
}
/* Color of the selected list item. */
QComboBox::item:selected {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background:yellow;
}
/* Indicator will shine through the label text if you don't make it hidden. */
QComboBox::indicator{
    background-color:transparent;
    selection-background-color:transparent;
    color:transparent;
    selection-color:transparent;
}
```