# QComboBox style for choosen item in drop-down list

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I want to style the highlighting of chosen item in drop-down of combobox.

The difference to other questions is that I do not want to style "selected" item (hovered over), but to style the already chosen item.

The default is some sort of tick which is painted over text. I want the chosen item to have bold text and no tick.

Or in worst case to just shifth the text to the right, to make the tick visible properly.

What I have is this:

[image]

Notice the 17th item which has tick over the number 17.

This is my stylesheet:

```
QComboBox
{
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    selection-background-color: #111;
    selection-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #565656, stop: 0.1 #525252, stop: 0.5 #4e4e4e, stop: 0.9 #4a4a4a, stop: 1 #464646);
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
    border-radius: 5;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 20px;
}


QComboBox:hover, QPushButton:hover
{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    color: white;
}

QComboBox:editable {
    background: red;
    color: pink;
}

QComboBox:on
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: white;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #2d2d2d, stop: 0.1 #2b2b2b, stop: 0.5 #292929, stop: 0.9 #282828, stop: 1 #252525);
    selection-background-color: #ffaa00;
}

QComboBox:!on
{
    color: white;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #666, stop: 0.1 #555, stop: 0.5 #555, stop: 0.9 #444, stop: 1 #333);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    color: black;
    selection-background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #111, stop: 1 #333);
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
     subcontrol-origin: padding;
     subcontrol-position: top right;
     width: 15px;
     color: white;
     border-left-width: 0px;
     border-left-color: darkgray;
     border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
     border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
     border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
     padding-left: 10px;
 }

QComboBox::down-arrow, QSpinBox::down-arrow, QTimeEdit::down-arrow, QDateEdit::down-arrow
{
     image: url(:/icons/down_arrow.png);
     width: 7px;
     height: 5px;
}
```

I was trying to override the item delagate:

```
ui->modeComboBox->setItemDelegate(new QStyledItemDelegate());
```

along with

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:selected style
```

Or override the view:

```
QListView * listView = new QListView(ui->modeComboBox);

listView->setStyleSheet("QListView::item {                              \
                         border-bottom: 5px solid white; margin:3px; }  \
                         QListView::item:selected {                     \
                         border-bottom: 5px solid black; margin:3px;    \
                         color: black;                                  \
                        }");
ui->modeComboBox->setView(listView);
```

but in both cases this totally disables the highlight of chosen item (which is 17th item)

UPDATE 1

I tested to set ::item:checked stylesheet but it didn't help:

```
QListView * listView = new QListView(ui->modeComboBox);
listView->setStyleSheet("QListView::item {                              \
                         border-bottom: 5px solid white; margin:3px; }  \
                         QListView::item:selected {                     \
                         border-bottom: 5px solid black; margin:3px;    \
                         color: black; }                                \
                         QListView::item:checked {                      \
                         background-color: green;                       \
                         color: green;}"
                         );
ui->modeComboBox->setView(listView);
```

Also I added this to stylesheet just to be sure:

```
QComboBox QListView::item:checked {
 background-color: green;
}
```

The result with 17 mode checked was (the black is just mouse hover):

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Ok I was able to change the weight of font of checked item, but I can not remove the tick from the item. I experimented with my stylesheet file and I found out that these two selectors are responsible for style of checked items highlightation:

```
QWidget:item:selected
{
     border: 0px solid #999900;
     background: transparent;
}
QWidget:item:checked
{
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

If I remove the ::item:selected then the ::item:checked do not work (it does not make the checked item bold) and the tick disappears.

On Qt forum they advised me to somehow shorten the "space for icons of combobox". I can not find the selector which is responsible for that.

Comment: Never tested but have you tried: `QComboBox QListView::item:checked { background-color: green; }`?

Comment: @iuliu I tried it didnt worked, updated the question.. thanks

Comment: @Iuliu your suggestion helped me, but I set it on QWidget.. but still I was not able to remove the ticker..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after lot of struggle I made some workaround.. its not best, its not proper, but it looks ok..

I added the bold effect in this way (it affect other widgets like checkable menu items, but I can live with that):

```
QWidget:item:selected
{
     border: 0px solid #999900;
     background: transparent;
}
QWidget:item:checked
{
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then when I am adding items I am prepending spaces into their text in order to shift it to the right.. I was trying so many things, but nothing affected the QAbstractItemView inside.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know it's really late, but for people having the same problem:
I found this at another question here: [Not able to hide Choice-Indicator of the QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609337/not-able-to-hide-choice-indicator-of-the-qcombobox)

This should hide the indicator/tick:

```
QComboBox::indicator{
    background-color:transparent;
    selection-background-color:transparent;
    color:transparent;
    selection-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had success with less specific stylesheet selectors and "padding-left":

```
QComboBox:item {
    padding-left: 20px;  /* move text right to make room for tick mark */
}
QComboBox:item:selected {
    padding-left: 20px;  /* move text right to make room for tick mark */
    border: 2px solid black;
}
QComboBox:item:checked {
    padding-left: 20px;  /* move text right to make room for tick mark */
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

(probably some unnecessary duplication in that, too!)

Comment: I think I tried that .. maybe in newer Qt its working properly.. however what I wanted to achieve was to have only bold and no ticker at all - but if this works its better solution than to add spaces (I do not have time to check your solution), maybe if someone here can try it at least and give feedback..

Comment: This fix the problem but it created a new one (Qt 5.9.2). The height of each item take the half of the height of the screen. I have to add a max-height...

Answer (score 1):

@Miklemyers answer removes the indicator/tick, but I found that the space is still left. To remove the space, I found I had to also use

```
QComboBox::item:selected {                                                                                                      
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me!:

```
myComboBox->setStyleSheet("QListView{color:black; background-color:white;}");
```

Comment: this doesnt look like it will highlight the *selected* items - it will just set all the text to black and background to white